# Select row with min value of element (if single/multiple rows are present in table)

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, greatest-n-per-group, min

Sample table -

```
rollno | subj_code | priority
1      | c45       | 0
1      | b68       | 1
1      | a98       | 2
2      | a98       | 0
```

I want to select a row with min value of `priority` for that I'm using the below query and its working fine if there are multiple rows in the database (as in the case for `rollno = 1`).

```
SELECT subj_code FROM priorities WHERE rollno = roll AND priority = (
    select min(priority) from priorities
)
```

But in my table it is possible that there is only one entry of a `rollno` which means only a single row and `priority` (as in the case for `rollno` = 2) and in this case the above queries don't give `subj_code` in return.
How to get the `subj_code` in return in this case?

Note -

1. different priority for a particular `rollno` can't have same values irrespective of the `subj_code` field.
   ie. the table below is not possible -

   rollno | subj_code | priority
   1      | c45       | 0
   1      | b68       | 0
2. Multiple rows can have same `priority` but the `rollno` needs to be different in that case.
3. the query gives correct result in this case -

   SELECT subj_code FROM priorities WHERE rollno = 1 AND priority = (
           select min(priority) from priorities
       )

but doesn't give result in this case -

```
SELECT subj_code FROM priorities WHERE rollno = 2 AND priority = (
        select min(priority) from priorities
    )
```

Comment: Are you passing in a `roll` variable -- what is that in your `where` criteria?  What should happen if you have multiple rows with the same minimum priority?

Comment: roll is just for reference that rollno is some integer.

Comment: So are you always returning a single row based on a rollno you pass in?  If so, instead of using the subquery, use `limit` -- `select code from priorities where rollno = roll order by priority limit 1` . . .

Comment: Glad it worked.  If you wanted to use a subquery, you'd need to include the same `where` criteria from your main query so that you only return the minimum priority for that row.

Comment: Sounds like [_groupwise-max_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max)

Answer (score 0):

```
with minprior as(
Select rollno as 'roll'
,min(priority) as 'minpri'
FROM priorities
Group by rollno)

Select rollno
,subj_code
,priority
From priorities inner join minprior
on rollno = roll
and priority = minpri
```

Comment: Can you share some context?

Comment: @Nico Hasse My understanding of this is that they want the entries with the minimum priority for each rollno and include subj_code in the results. The easiest way I know how to do this is to create a CTE to get the minimum value for each rollno. Then inner joining the original table to the CTE on rollno and priority you can include the subj_code.